# Web service Rest using Angular2 and spring with Enum Types

Tags: spring, typescript, enums

I want to seed an object with format JSON that have an attribute with type enum
when I lanch my request I fet error 403

this is my service in front side

```
export enum DocumentComponentType {
    DIV_12,
    DIV_4_4_4,
    DIV_4_8,
    DIV_8_4,
    DIV_6_6,
}
export interface DocumentComponent {
    id: number;
    type: DocumentComponentType;
    // documentContents: DocumentContent[];
}

 this.gridService.addDocumentComponent({id: 0, type: DocumentComponentType.DIV_8_4}, 6)
                    .subscribe(data => {
                            this.documentComponent = data;
                        },
                        error => alert('Erreur ' + error),
                        () => {
                            console.log("finished  ");
                        }
                    );
```

and in server side

this is my class

```
public class DocumentComponent {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    DocumentComponentType  type;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "documentComponent")
    private List<DocumentContent> documentContents;
    @ManyToOne
    Document document;
    DocumentComponent(){

    }
}
```

and my enum

```
public enum  DocumentComponentType {
    DIV_12,
    DIV_4_4_4,
    DIV_4_8,
    DIV_8_4,
    DIV_6_6,
}
```

I get error 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Looks into the Server logfile. There you should see the root cause of the exception

Comment: this is my error in server 
NULL violates the NOT NULL constraint for the column "id"  BUT  me I have generatedValue

Answer (score 0):

> I get error 500 (Internal Server Error)

This means that there is an error on the server. The code you have posted is client side code.

## Fix

Look at the server side logs (and or) attach a debugger to the server to see what is going on there.

## More

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error The error is a generic error message which essentially means that something *unexpected happened*.